# IIS Deployment Behaviour on .Net Core App (403 and 404 errors)

Tags: .net-core, iis

Lets say my domain is example.com
There is several applications in this domain such as example.com -> auth or example.com -> services.

There is several apps inside services such as: example.com -> services -> sub-application1, example.com -> services -> sub-application2 and so on.

New sub application would be example.com -> services -> sub-applicationNew, and this application is .Net core 3.1 like others.

Interestingly if i go from browser to example.com/services/sub-applicationNew i am getting 403. But if i copy files of another application no such error occurs.

Local version of this app is like example.local.com/services/sub-applicationNew and it gives 404, it is normal because this application is web-api. If i go to some endpoint like example.local.com/services/sub-applicationNew/api/public/test it gives me output.

Again interestingly, if i go example.com/services/sub-applicationNew/api/public/test it gives me 404 :) but it is exists i know.

My question is: Which configuration is causing this behaviour on iis that i want to know to fix it.

to sum up:

example.com/services/sub-applicationNew gives 403

example.com/services/sub-applicationNew/api/public/test gives 404

example.com/services/sub-applicationNew (copy other app files on iss to site folder) it works

example.local.com/services/sub-applicationNew gives 404 (it is normal)

example.local.com/services/sub-applicationNew/api/public/test gives 200 with result.

sorry for my english, i hope i explain my situation.

Answer (score 0):

After several days unresolvable state, i try to ask from this platform but we found it in a few hours after posting question :)

Main reason was web.config file. it was coppied during publish and modified only by hand.

i will paste working working web.config below, for giving you an opinion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\application.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

important point in here is this section:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

that was missing and iis could not able to run the app i think.

Hope this solves problems who encounter with.

Comment: When you have nested applications under a site on IIS, any incoming HTTP requests must be routed to the correct application by your routing settings (more can be found in articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Of course, when you use `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`, you control the routing from the entire application level but it would still be beneficial to know how routing works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and article, i will be looking there. Best regards.